# How to schedule a background task

Tags: android

There seems to be a couple of ways to go about having a background task being executed. My usecase is to have my app fetch a datafeed every x minutes, regardless of my gui is running, and regardless of whether the phone is sleeping or not.

I use an alarmmanager to schedule an intent matching a broadcastreceiver. in the onRecieve method i start a service (startService), which spawns an AsyncTask. The task fetches data and stores it and then stopSelf() the service.

in the onRecieve method i aquire a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, before starting the service, and just before calling stopSelf() in the service, i release it again.

Is this really the best way to do it? Do i even need the service in this scenario?

I experience odd behaviour with this setup, where the setup works for hours and then suddenly stops, which makes it very hard to debug.

Does anyone have a simple foolproof method to achive the same end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I use an alarmmanager to schedule an
>   intent matching a broadcastreceiver.
>   in the onRecieve method i start a
>   service (startService), which spawns
>   an AsyncTask. The task fetches data
>   and stores it and then stopSelf() the
>   service.

I'd suggest using an `IntentService` instead of the `AsyncTask`/`stopSelf()` pattern, but otherwise this seems sound.

> in the onRecieve method i aquire a
>   PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, before starting the
>   service, and just before calling
>   stopSelf() in the service, i release
>   it again.

That makes sense. I do much the same thing in my [`WakefulIntentService`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) open source component.

> Is this really the best way to do it?

You certainly seem close.

> Do i even need the service in this
>   scenario?

If what you need to do on the scheduled basis is guaranteed to only take a second or so, you could do that in the `BroadcastReceiver`. Otherwise, you need to have the work be done on a background thread, and `BroadcastReceivers` cannot fork background threads.

Comment: aha! so i couldn't start my asynctask in the broadcastreciever? even if i aquire the wakelock in onrecieve and release it when the asynctask finishes? 

thanks for the info, and i guess i'll need to bughunt some more for my odd alarm stops

Comment: "so i couldn't start my asynctask in the broadcastreciever?" I don't think so, but I haven't tried it. AsyncTask has its own thread pool, and it's *possible* that you can safely run an AsyncTask from a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of using IntentService, didn't know about that. Now i have dropped my Service and the AsyncTask. Much more elegant.

Comment: At what point does this pattern become better then having a service with a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (or a `TimerTask`) ? I'd imagine if the calls are very frequent you don't want to set the alarm, and if its once per day, you want this. But where -if there is indeed- is the line?

Comment: @Nanne: No idea. My rough-cut guess is around the one-minute mark. This is a question I hope to more scientifically answer in the coming months.

Comment: When looking in to the alarms, it seems that there are interfals predefined of which the smallest seems to be `AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES`. So smaller then that would not be possible using -for instance- `setInexactRepeating()`. That might be a practical "flipping point"